# ObjectID generated by server on pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo (python module for mongodb).

I want the ObjectID to be created automatically by the server, however it seems to be created by pymongo itself when we don't specify it.

The problem it raises is that I use ObjectID to sort by time (by just sorting by the _id field). However it seems that it is using the time set on each computer so we cannot truly rely on it.
Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call [`save`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.save) and pass it a document without an `_id` field, you can force the server to add the `_id` instead of the client by setting the (enigmatically-named) `manipulate` option to `False`:

```
coll.save({'foo': 'bar'}, manipulate=False)
```

Comment: @user3474490 I guess the drawback would be when you use [sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/) this would fail (ObjectId will be generated by sharding servers). If you are not going to, this is definitely better than mine solution.

Comment: @user3474490 Shouldn't be any performance hit; it simply relocates the point at which the `_id` is generated.

Comment: @yaoxing According to [mongodb doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#sharded-clusters) it seems that this limitation is for update and remove. If I use insert is there still this limitation on sharded clusters?

Comment: @koushkov What I mean is when in a sharding environment, there will be several different `mongod` working in different servers. ObjectId will not be generated by one server anymore, thus you'll run into the same situation just like now.

Comment: @yaoxing ok fair point. I guess when I reach that point I might implement your method

Answer (score 1):

I'm not Python user but I'm afraid there's no way to generate _id by server. For performance reasons _id is always generated by driver thus when you insert a document you don't need to do another query to get the _id back.

Here's a possible way you can do it by generating a int sequence _id, just like the `IDENTITY` ID of SqlServer. To do this, you need to keep a record in you certain collection for example in my project there's a `seed`, which has only one record:

```
{_id: ObjectId("..."), seqNo: 1 }
```

The trick is, you have to use [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) to keep the find and modify in the same "transaction".

```
var idSeed = db.seed.findAndModify({
    query: {},
    sort: {seqNo: 1},
    update: { $inc: { seqNo: 1 } },
    new: false
});
var id = idSeed.seqNo;
```

This way you'll have all you instances get a unique sequence# and you can use it to sort the records.

Comment: Smart implementation! However it seems the answer from JohnnyHK limits any additional query for getting the seed

Comment: Just a question, should not you apply your $inc on seqNo?

Comment: @koushkov Yes my fault, it should be on `seqNo`