# MongoDB C# Driver and server generated ObjectIds

Tags: c#, multithreading, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there a way get server generated ObjectIds instead of C# Driver generated ObjectIds? Using `MongoCollectionSettings.AssignIdOnInsert = false` only gets you zeroed out ObjectIds. I'm doing multi-threaded inserts on a capped collection, and I'm seeing threads switch between the ObjectId generation and the insert. This causes out of order ObjectIds in a collection that's supposed to be ordered for tailed cursors sorting on natural order. Right now I'm using a static lock object for the inserts, but that won't help with different executables/servers.

It appears this is possible with the pymongo driver: [ObjectID generated by server on pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111937/objectid-generated-by-server-on-pymongo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Getting documents in insertion order from a capped collection

Capped collections maintain documents in insertion order, so you should ideally use [natural order](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/use-capped-collections-for-fast-writes-and-reads/#use-natural-order-for-fast-reads) rather than relying on the timestamp in the generated `_id`. Your tailable cursor will be reading documents in natural order, so should not make any assumptions based on the `_id`.

#### Generating server-side `_id`

To generate `_id` on the server side using the C# driver you need to:

- set the class attribute `[BsonIgnoreIfDefault]`
- set the collection attribute `AssignIdOnInsert = false`
- insert a document without an `_id`

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

public class MyDoc {
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public ObjectId? Id;
    public int X;
}

public static class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient(); // connect to localhost
        var server = client.GetServer ();
        var database = server.GetDatabase("test");
        var collectionSettings = new MongoCollectionSettings { AssignIdOnInsert = false };
        var collection = database.GetCollection<MyDoc>("nullid", collectionSettings);

        // Insert document without _id
        collection.Insert(new MyDoc { X = 1});
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use natural order only and my cursor should die for any reason, how would I formulate the query to recreate the cursor? If I use greater than last retrieved ObjectId, I could get items I already processed. Is there any way to query greater than the natural order of an ObjectId?